# JQuery, use selector to get images by their border attribute (not the css border styling)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to round up all images that have a specific attribute and place. My images look like this:

```
<img src='http...' border=3 class=grid_pic>
```

And here is my attempt:

```
$('.grid_pic:has(border=3)').each(function(){alert(1);});
```

But the alert doesn't shout. If I remove the has:border/has:border=3, it shouts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it like that:

```
[attribute=value]   $(’[rel=external]‘);
```

Example:

```
$('.grid_pic[border=3]').each(function(){alert(1);});
```

Comment: @Max Shawabkeh thanks for editing my answer, it must be without space before the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

`$('.grid_pic[border=3]').each(function(){alert(1);});`